# Registering to the Outlook appointment item 'closed' event using VSTO

Tags: vsto

I am writing an Outlook add-in using VSTO 2010 for Office 2007.

How can I register to the Outlook appointment item 'closed' event?

Cheers,
Doron

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access it via the inspector.

In Outlook each item has an associated window, that window is known as the inspector. So you can go:

```
var inspector = appointmentItem.GetInspector();
inspector.Close += Closed;
```

UPDATE:

This is one of the crappy things about the office api, there is actually a close event AND a close method.

Cast to InspectorEvents_10_Event interface first.

`((InspectorEvents_10_Event)inspector).Close += Closed;`

Comment: The 'inspector.Close' is a method not an event. Am I missing something?

Comment: They imported the crappyness from outlook.vba into vsto.c#  :-((