# Detect if outlook inspector window has closed

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

For an addin for Outlook 2016 I have to detect if an inspector window (email window) has closed.

I've found a guid on the microsoft website but I can't seem to get it working.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184620.aspx 
I Can't seem to find a way to add a method to the close event

```
((Outlook.InspectorEvents_Event)inspector).Close +=
        new Outlook.InspectorEvents_CloseEventHandler(
        OutlookInspectorWindow_Close);
```

Has anyone found a way to get it working?
I don't seem to have an InspectorEvents_Events object.

Thanks in advance

---

---

---

## **Edit**

My close isn't an event, it's a method, as mentioned here
[Registering to the Outlook appointment item 'closed' event using VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130026/registering-to-the-outlook-appointment-item-closed-event-using-vsto) 
You have to force a cast using:

```
((InspectorEvents_10_Event)inspector).Close += Closed;
```

I didn't get it to work because my compiler didn't suggest InspectorEvents_Event or InspectorEvents_10_Event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the inspector object to the [InspectorEvents_10_Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspectorevents_10_event.aspx)  interface:

```
        var inspector = Inspector as InspectorEvents_10_Event;
        if (inspector != null)
        {
            inspector.Close += OnInspectorClose;
        }
```

Comment: Hey Eugene, thanks for the responds. I also found out it had to be casted to fire the event and it fixed it. However this event also gets fired when I change mail but keep the window open. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Most probably you used up/down buttons, right? In that case an inspector window is closed/opened too.